# Is the Digicert USB token needed for every single .exe code-signing operation? (EV code-signing certificate)

Tags: code-signing, code-signing-certificate, digicert

I have a Digicert SafeNet USB token (EV code signing certificate), that I use with `digicertutil.exe` each time I need to sign a .exe file.

Problem: I don't want to have to bring this sensitive USB token with me all the time. But still I'd like to be able to codesign a .exe even when the hardware token is not with me (I prefer to let the USB token in a secure place, once for all, and not carry it with me).

Is there a way with `digicertutil.exe` or another tool, to save the certificate into a file, such that I can codesign future .exe without the hardware token?

Or is there a way to allow *"Don't ask for the hardware token in the next 15 days, but just the password"*?

[image]

Comment: Isn't hardware tokens prime purpose to not allow sign anything without token present?  I don't know about particular hardware, but usually they contain private key, which cannot be extracted.

Comment: Thanks @Arvo. This seems to show that I have to carry the USB token with me every time I need to sign code, which is not very convenient (it's a non-trivial process to get a new hardware token, which takes time and money, so I preferred not to keep the token with me all the time to avoid the risk of losing it).

Answer (score 0):

I've never used a code-signing certificate, and have only an elementary understanding of certificates in general, but I did some searching online, and found the following resources:

[This website uses something called "OpenToken".](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1271890/EV-Code-Signing-with-a-Hardware-Token) It appears to do exactly what you want. It was posted in December 2018, though. I don't know whether any changes have been made to the USBs to render this code useless.

[This superuser answer also seems to do what you want.](https://superuser.com/questions/609899/how-to-make-a-virtual-usb-drive-in-windows)

[It's also possible that Digicert will duplicate it for you.](https://docs.digicert.com/manage-certificates/duplicate-ssltls-certificate/)

> All DigiCert certificates come with unlimited free duplicate issues.

Note that any attempts to duplicate the USB may result in the USB getting reset, [as this Quora answer mentions.](https://www.quora.com/What-if-someone-say-an-IT-expert-took-possession-of-my-USB-DSC-device-Proxeykey-digital-signature-for-a-day-then-is-it-any-how-possible-that-he-may-clone-hack-it-for-making-a-duplicate-and-misuse-it-Please-advise)

Also, note that [duplicating a certificate USB may be a very, very, very bad idea.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127769/how-to-share-ev-code-signing-certificate-with-usb-token-with-other-developers)

**Edit:**
[This Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/38927) notes that USB certificates can just be copied, in which case, maybe you don't need to go to all the trouble of using third-party software to duplicate your certificate.